# custom navbar style doesnt work correctly

Tags: html, css

I have custom navbar, not any bootstrap or something else.

I tryed one tab is left and dropdowns are middle and one tab is right side.

But right side tab isnt inside navbar.

I dont understand why it is going out of navbar if it is in ul tag. Maybe someone can explain that.

HTML code:

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="nav_wrapper">
    <ul>
      <div id="left">
        <li>
          <a href="#">item #1</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div id="mid">
        <li> <a href="#">dropdown #1</a>

            <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">dropdown #1 item #1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">dropdown #1 item #2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">dropdown #1 item #3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">dropdown #2</a>

            <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">dropdown #2 item #1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">dropdown #2 item #2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">dropdown #2 item #3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">dropdown #3</a>

            <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">dropdown #3 item #1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">dropdown #3 item #2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">dropdown #3 item #3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">item #2</a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- Nav wrapper end -->
```

Style code:

```
    body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#nav {
background-color: #222;
}
#left{
float: left;
}

#mid{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center
}

#right{
float: right;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: #CCC;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 5px solid #222;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-left: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #699;
}
```

Added html and style code here.

Problem is right side isnt in navbar.

I think in divs is problem.

Comment: Please copy your code into the question.  External hosting may expire, rendering the question useless.

Comment: @roelofs edited post and added code.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try

```
#nav_wrapper ul{
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:flex;
}
```

and now you DON'T have to give `float:left` and `float:right` to the `#left` and `#right` divs; and your right div will be aligned on the right end.

OR

Add the following codes to your existing styles, to align your third item on the right end.

```
#nav{
 background-color: #222;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#mid{
  float:left;
}
```